# desplazar elementos hacia la derecha con JS

Tags: javascript

Lo que tengo que lograr es que cada elemento del arreglo se desplace las veces que quiera hacia la derecha, por ejemplo:
rotar([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) debe retornar [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
Lo que hice fue: Es una idea sacada de internet, pero he intentado y no me sale que vaya de izquierda a derecha

```
function rotar (arr, num){

   return [...arr.slice(num), ...arr.slice(0, num)];
}
```

Otra forma que quise hacer:

```
function rotar (str, num){

   for (let i=0; i < str.length; i++){
      let sacar= str[str.length -1]+","+str
   }
   return sacar
}

rotar([1,2,3,4,5]) //======>  [5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

eliminar ultimo elemento de el arreglo con arr.lenght -1 y agregar con unshift el valor retornado de arr.lenght -1 , y me sale, o sea se mueve pepro no logro que se mueva las veces que yo quiera, aun que sea una orientacion me serviria, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es sólo el enunciado de una tarea. Creo que tienes el concepto erróneo de que aquí le hacemos la tarea a los flojos, felizmente no es así, por lo cuál tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Considera editar tu pregunta y demostrar con un [mcve] que has intentado resolver el problema por tu cuenta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu primer intento es casi correcto; solo te ha faltado tener en cuenta que, en la función [`slice( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), si algún argumento es negativo, indica **desde el final**. Con eso en mente, es muy sencillo hacer lo que pretendes:

```js
const arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

function rotar( arr, steps ) {
    if( steps > arr.length ) {
        steps = steps % arr.length;
    } else if( ( steps == arr.length ) || ( steps == 0 ) ) {
        return arr.slice( );
    }

    return [ ... arr.slice( -steps ), ... arr.slice( 0, -steps ) ];
}

console.log( rotar( arr, 0 ) )
console.log( rotar( arr, 1 ) )
console.log( rotar( arr, 2 ) )
console.log( rotar( arr, 4 ) )
console.log( rotar( arr, 5 ) )
console.log( rotar( arr, 6 ) )
```